# A role play poem about escaping from a time loop

Tags: product-identification, role-playing-poem

I do remember a role playing poem, in which you play a mundane scene for like 3 minutues, before a time loop starts. The players then try to break out of the time loop, which they have a chance to do, because they have some super powers.
I assumed I had seen it on the blog [Nørwegian Style](https://norwegianstyle.wordpress.com/), but searching through that site with keywords such as “time loop” were not helpful. Since there are some poems posted on [Story Games](http://story-games.com) I goolged there, as well, but to no avail either. I've also checked [Gizmet Game Poems](http://gamepoems.gizmet.com) without success.

Where can I find this poem?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I think this is the one you're looking for:

[The Endless Meta Spiral](https://norwegianstyle.wordpress.com/2008/03/31/the-endless-meta-spiral/) by Martin Bull Gudmundsen.

> The winner of the 2008 Role-Playing Poem Slam at HolmCon. A quote from the text: “Play yourselves as you were two minutes ago. After two minutes, M. says: “We’re sitting down to play this game. It’s two minutes ago.””